# Built in raytracing?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, linear-algebra

Relating to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696338/how-do-i-render-and-detect-a-line-of-sight/) i was wondering if .NET has any libs (or a function) i can use to detect if one point collides with another.

I am not sure what angles i should use but is there some function like this

```
func(point src, rect target, angle, distanceOfVision, listPointOrRectOfWalls)
```

Pretty unlikely but i dont know a formula or how to start. Its a quick and dirty prototype. I am thinking of writing the func but dropping angle making line of sight a rectangle and check if any wall points are between src and target.

Comment: I honestly have no clue, but could this be somethat that [XNA](http://www.xna.com/) provides?

Comment: Just for fun: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2007/Nov-16.html ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve the problem as such:

1. Three points of the rectangle define the plane that the rectangle lies in.
2. Instead of representing the line as a point and an angle, represent it as a point and a vector: `source_point + direction_vector * t`. If you set `t = 1` you have two points defining your line.
3. Compute the intersection of the line with the plane: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection
4. Check if the intersection point is contained within the rectangle.